# Why would ISNULL improve the performance of a query?

Tags: performance, t-sql, sql-server-2005

We're currently trying to speedup some queries and we've run into something which I (not a DBA just a .NET developer) cannot explain or comprehent. We're running this query on SQL Server 2005.

We have the following query (made small and simple for the sake of argument);

```
SELECT    
    *
FROM    
    RandomTable 
WHERE   
    MoneyColumn <> 0
GROUP BY
    SomeColumn
```

This query run in around **three** seconds, then we randomly tried to following to speed it up (shot in the dark really)

```
SELECT    
    *
FROM    
    RandomTable 
WHERE   
    isnull(MoneyColumn,0) <> 0
GROUP BY
    SomeColumn
```

This reduces the query speed to around **one** second..

This column has no NULL values (yet due to the database design beeing HORRIBLE) it is however NULLABLE...

Is the fact that it's NULLABLE making SQL Server do something to account for this making it slow where the ISNULL isn't beeing mentioned? I simply have no idea why the ISNULL would make it perform faster (and by such a big margin). I'd think SQL would actually have more to do when there is a ISNULL statement in the query.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

**EDIT** Execution plans added

**With ISNULL**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ShowPlanXML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="1.0" Build="9.00.5000.00" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan">
  <BatchSequence>
    <Batch>
      <Statements>
        <StmtSimple StatementCompId="1" StatementEstRows="9019.76" StatementId="1" StatementOptmLevel="FULL" StatementSubTreeCost="1.48105" StatementText="SELECT    debiteur_id, MIN(Faktuurdatum) AS OldestOpenInvoiceDate, ISNULL(SUM(Totaal_Open),0) AS TotalOpenAmount&#xD;&#xA;FROM    dbo.tbl_Faktuur &#xD;&#xA;WHERE   (Afgehandeld_NeeJa = 0 OR Afgehandeld_NeeJa IS NULL)&#xD;&#xA;AND        (ISNULL(Totaal_Open,0) &lt;&gt; 0) &#xD;&#xA;--AND        (Totaal_Open &lt;&gt; 0) &#xD;&#xA;GROUP BY debiteur_id" StatementType="SELECT">
          <StatementSetOptions ANSI_NULLS="false" ANSI_PADDING="false" ANSI_WARNINGS="false" ARITHABORT="true" CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="false" NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="false" />
          <QueryPlan DegreeOfParallelism="1" MemoryGrant="1520" CachedPlanSize="54" CompileTime="11" CompileCPU="11" CompileMemory="704">
            <RelOp AvgRowSize="23" EstimateCPU="0.000901976" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="9019.76" LogicalOp="Compute Scalar" NodeId="0" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Compute Scalar" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="1.48105">
              <OutputList>
                <ColumnReference Database="[directpay]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_Faktuur]" Column="Debiteur_ID" />
                <ColumnReference Column="Expr1003" />
                <ColumnReference Column="Expr1005" />
              </OutputList>
              <ComputeScalar>
                <DefinedValues>
                  <DefinedValue>
                    <ColumnReference Column="Expr1005" />
                    <ScalarOperator ScalarString="isnull([Expr1004],($0.0000))">
                      <Intrinsic FunctionName="isnull">
                        <ScalarOperator>
                          <Identifier>
                            <ColumnReference Column="Expr1004" />
                          </Identifier>
                        </ScalarOperator>
                        <ScalarOperator>
                          <Const ConstValue="($0.0000)" />
                        </ScalarOperator>
                      </Intrinsic>
                    </ScalarOperator>
                  </DefinedValue>
                </DefinedValues>
                <RelOp AvgRowSize="23" EstimateCPU="0.291662" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="9019.76" LogicalOp="Compute Scalar" NodeId="1" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Compute Scalar" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="1.48014">
                  <OutputList>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[directpay]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_Faktuur]" Column="Debiteur_ID" />
                    <ColumnReference Column="Expr1003" />
                    <ColumnReference Column="Expr1004" />
                  </OutputList>
                  <ComputeScalar>
                    <DefinedValues>
                      <DefinedValue>
                        <ColumnReference Column="Expr1004" />
                        <ScalarOperator ScalarString="CASE WHEN [Expr1013]=(0) THEN NULL ELSE [Expr1014] END">
                          <IF>
                            <Condition>
                              <ScalarOperator>
                                <Compare CompareOp="EQ">
                                  <ScalarOperator>
                                    <Identifier>
                                      <ColumnReference Column="Expr1013" />
                                    </Identifier>
                                  </ScalarOperator>
                                  <ScalarOperator>
                                    <Const ConstValue="(0)" />
                                  </ScalarOperator>
                                </Compare>
                              </ScalarOperator>
                            </Condition>
                            <Then>
                              <ScalarOperator>
                                <Const ConstValue="NULL" />
                              </ScalarOperator>
                            </Then>
                            <Else>
                              <ScalarOperator>
                                <Identifier>
                                  <ColumnReference Column="Expr1014" />
                                </Identifier>
                              </ScalarOperator>
                            </Else>
                          </IF>
                        </ScalarOperator>
                      </DefinedValue>
                    </DefinedValues>
                    <RelOp AvgRowSize="23" EstimateCPU="0.291662" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="9019.76" LogicalOp="Aggregate" NodeId="2" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Hash Match" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="1.48014">
                      <OutputList>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[directpay]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_Faktuur]" Column="Debiteur_ID" />
                        <ColumnReference Column="Expr1003" />
                        <ColumnReference Column="Expr1013" />
                        <ColumnReference Column="Expr1014" />
                      </OutputList>
                      <MemoryFractions Input="1" Output="1" />
                      <RunTimeInformation>
                        <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="156794" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
                      </RunTimeInformation>
                      <Hash>
                        <DefinedValues>
                          <DefinedValue>
                            <ColumnReference Column="Expr1003" />
                            <ScalarOperator ScalarString="MIN([directpay].[dbo].[tbl_Faktuur].[Faktuurdatum])">
                              <Aggregate AggType="MIN" Distinct="false">
                                <ScalarOperator>
                                  <Identifier>
                                    <ColumnReference Database="[directpay]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_Faktuur]" Column="Faktuurdatum" />
                                  </Identifier>
                                </ScalarOperator>
                              </Aggregate>
                            </ScalarOperator>
                          </DefinedValue>
                          <DefinedValue>
                            <ColumnReference Column="Expr1013" />
                            <ScalarOperator ScalarString="COUNT_BIG([directpay].[dbo].[tbl_Faktuur].[Totaal_Open])">
                              <Aggregate AggType="COUNT_BIG" Distinct="false">
                                <ScalarOperator>
                                  <Identifier>
                                    <ColumnReference Database="[directpay]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_Faktuur]" Column="Totaal_Open" />
                                  </Identifier>
                                </ScalarOperator>
                              </Aggregate>
                            </ScalarOperator>
                          </DefinedValue>
                          <DefinedValue>
                            <ColumnReference Column="Expr1014" />
                            <ScalarOperator ScalarString="SUM([directpay].[dbo].[tbl_Faktuur].[Totaal_Open])">
                              <Aggregate AggType="SUM" Distinct="false">
                                <ScalarOperator>
                                  <Identifier>
                                    <ColumnReference Database="[directpay]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_Faktuur]" Column="Totaal_Open" />
                                  </Identifier>
                                </ScalarOperator>
                              </Aggregate>
                            </ScalarOperator>
                          </DefinedValue>
                        </DefinedValues>
                        <HashKeysBuild>
                          <ColumnReference Database="[directpay]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_Faktuur]" Column="Debiteur_ID" />
                        </HashKeysBuild>
                        <RelOp AvgRowSize="23" EstimateCPU="0.255" EstimateIO="0.634196" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="27420" LogicalOp="Index Seek" NodeId="4" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Index Seek" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.889196">
                          <OutputList>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[directpay]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_Faktuur]" Column="Debiteur_ID" />
                            <ColumnReference Database="[directpay]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_Faktuur]" Column="Faktuurdatum" />
                            <ColumnReference Database="[directpay]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_Faktuur]" Column="Totaal_Open" />
                          </OutputList>
                          <RunTimeInformation>
                            <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="298726" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
                          </RunTimeInformation>
                          <IndexScan Ordered="true" ScanDirection="FORWARD" ForcedIndex="false" NoExpandHint="false">
                            <DefinedValues>
                              <DefinedValue>
                                <ColumnReference Database="[directpay]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_Faktuur]" Column="Debiteur_ID" />
                              </DefinedValue>
                              <DefinedValue>
                                <ColumnReference Database="[directpay]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_Faktuur]" Column="Faktuurdatum" />
                              </DefinedValue>
                              <DefinedValue>
                                <ColumnReference Database="[directpay]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_Faktuur]" Column="Totaal_Open" />
                              </DefinedValue>
                            </DefinedValues>
                            <Object Database="[directpay]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_Faktuur]" Index="[_dta_index_tbl_Faktuur_5_583009158__K13_K9_K19_K2_5]" />
                            <SeekPredicates>
                              <SeekPredicate>
                                <Prefix ScanType="EQ">
                                  <RangeColumns>
                                    <ColumnReference Database="[directpay]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_Faktuur]" Column="Afgehandeld_NeeJa" />
                                  </RangeColumns>
                                  <RangeExpressions>
                                    <ScalarOperator ScalarString="(0)">
                                      <Const ConstValue="(0)" />
                                    </ScalarOperator>
                                  </RangeExpressions>
                                </Prefix>
                              </SeekPredicate>
                            </SeekPredicates>
                            <Predicate>
                              <ScalarOperator ScalarString="isnull([directpay].[dbo].[tbl_Faktuur].[Totaal_Open],($0.0000))&lt;($0.0000) OR isnull([directpay].[dbo].[tbl_Faktuur].[Totaal_Open],($0.0000))&gt;($0.0000)">
                                <Logical Operation="OR">
                                  <ScalarOperator>
                                    <Compare CompareOp="LT">
                                      <ScalarOperator>
                                        <Intrinsic FunctionName="isnull">
                                          <ScalarOperator>
                                            <Identifier>
                                              <ColumnReference Database="[directpay]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_Faktuur]" Column="Totaal_Open" />
                                            </Identifier>
                                          </ScalarOperator>
                                          <ScalarOperator>
                                            <Const ConstValue="($0.0000)" />
                                          </ScalarOperator>
                                        </Intrinsic>
                                      </ScalarOperator>
                                      <ScalarOperator>
                                        <Const ConstValue="($0.0000)" />
                                      </ScalarOperator>
                                    </Compare>
                                  </ScalarOperator>
                                  <ScalarOperator>
                                    <Compare CompareOp="GT">
                                      <ScalarOperator>
                                        <Intrinsic FunctionName="isnull">
                                          <ScalarOperator>
                                            <Identifier>
                                              <ColumnReference Database="[directpay]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_Faktuur]" Column="Totaal_Open" />
                                            </Identifier>
                                          </ScalarOperator>
                                          <ScalarOperator>
                                            <Const ConstValue="($0.0000)" />
                                          </ScalarOperator>
                                        </Intrinsic>
                                      </ScalarOperator>
                                      <ScalarOperator>
                                        <Const ConstValue="($0.0000)" />
                                      </ScalarOperator>
                                    </Compare>
                                  </ScalarOperator>
                                </Logical>
                              </ScalarOperator>
                            </Predicate>
                          </IndexScan>
                        </RelOp>
                      </Hash>
                    </RelOp>
                  </ComputeScalar>
                </RelOp>
              </ComputeScalar>
            </RelOp>
          </QueryPlan>
        </StmtSimple>
      </Statements>
    </Batch>
  </BatchSequence>
</ShowPlanXML>
```

**Without ISNULL**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ShowPlanXML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="1.0" Build="9.00.5000.00" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan">
  <BatchSequence>
    <Batch>
      <Statements>
        <StmtSimple StatementCompId="1" StatementEstRows="1322.43" StatementId="1" StatementOptmLevel="FULL" StatementOptmEarlyAbortReason="GoodEnoughPlanFound" StatementSubTreeCost="0.274954" StatementText="SELECT    debiteur_id, MIN(Faktuurdatum) AS OldestOpenInvoiceDate, ISNULL(SUM(Totaal_Open),0) AS TotalOpenAmount&#xD;&#xA;FROM    dbo.tbl_Faktuur &#xD;&#xA;WHERE   (Afgehandeld_NeeJa = 0 OR Afgehandeld_NeeJa IS NULL)&#xD;&#xA;--AND        (ISNULL(Totaal_Open,0) &lt;&gt; 0) &#xD;&#xA;AND        (Totaal_Open &lt;&gt; 0) &#xD;&#xA;GROUP BY debiteur_id" StatementType="SELECT">
          <StatementSetOptions ANSI_NULLS="false" ANSI_PADDING="false" ANSI_WARNINGS="false" ARITHABORT="true" CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="false" NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="false" />
          <QueryPlan CachedPlanSize="47" CompileTime="9" CompileCPU="9" CompileMemory="528">
            <RelOp AvgRowSize="23" EstimateCPU="0.000132243" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="1322.43" LogicalOp="Compute Scalar" NodeId="0" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Compute Scalar" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.274954">
              <OutputList>
                <ColumnReference Database="[directpay]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_Faktuur]" Column="Debiteur_ID" />
                <ColumnReference Column="Expr1003" />
                <ColumnReference Column="Expr1005" />
              </OutputList>
              <ComputeScalar>
                <DefinedValues>
                  <DefinedValue>
                    <ColumnReference Column="Expr1005" />
                    <ScalarOperator ScalarString="isnull([Expr1004],($0.0000))">
                      <Intrinsic FunctionName="isnull">
                        <ScalarOperator>
                          <Identifier>
                            <ColumnReference Column="Expr1004" />
                          </Identifier>
                        </ScalarOperator>
                        <ScalarOperator>
                          <Const ConstValue="($0.0000)" />
                        </ScalarOperator>
                      </Intrinsic>
                    </ScalarOperator>
                  </DefinedValue>
                </DefinedValues>
                <RelOp AvgRowSize="23" EstimateCPU="0.167304" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="1322.43" LogicalOp="Aggregate" NodeId="1" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Hash Match" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.274822">
                  <OutputList>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[directpay]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_Faktuur]" Column="Debiteur_ID" />
                    <ColumnReference Column="Expr1003" />
                    <ColumnReference Column="Expr1004" />
                  </OutputList>
                  <MemoryFractions Input="0" Output="0" />
                  <Hash>
                    <DefinedValues>
                      <DefinedValue>
                        <ColumnReference Column="Expr1003" />
                        <ScalarOperator ScalarString="MIN([directpay].[dbo].[tbl_Faktuur].[Faktuurdatum])">
                          <Aggregate AggType="MIN" Distinct="false">
                            <ScalarOperator>
                              <Identifier>
                                <ColumnReference Database="[directpay]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_Faktuur]" Column="Faktuurdatum" />
                              </Identifier>
                            </ScalarOperator>
                          </Aggregate>
                        </ScalarOperator>
                      </DefinedValue>
                      <DefinedValue>
                        <ColumnReference Column="Expr1004" />
                        <ScalarOperator ScalarString="SUM([directpay].[dbo].[tbl_Faktuur].[Totaal_Open])">
                          <Aggregate AggType="SUM" Distinct="false">
                            <ScalarOperator>
                              <Identifier>
                                <ColumnReference Database="[directpay]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_Faktuur]" Column="Totaal_Open" />
                              </Identifier>
                            </ScalarOperator>
                          </Aggregate>
                        </ScalarOperator>
                      </DefinedValue>
                    </DefinedValues>
                    <HashKeysBuild>
                      <ColumnReference Database="[directpay]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_Faktuur]" Column="Debiteur_ID" />
                    </HashKeysBuild>
                    <RelOp AvgRowSize="23" EstimateCPU="0.030319" EstimateIO="0.0771991" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="27420" LogicalOp="Index Seek" NodeId="2" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Index Seek" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.107518">
                      <OutputList>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[directpay]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_Faktuur]" Column="Debiteur_ID" />
                        <ColumnReference Database="[directpay]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_Faktuur]" Column="Faktuurdatum" />
                        <ColumnReference Database="[directpay]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_Faktuur]" Column="Totaal_Open" />
                      </OutputList>
                      <IndexScan Ordered="true" ScanDirection="FORWARD" ForcedIndex="false" NoExpandHint="false">
                        <DefinedValues>
                          <DefinedValue>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[directpay]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_Faktuur]" Column="Debiteur_ID" />
                          </DefinedValue>
                          <DefinedValue>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[directpay]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_Faktuur]" Column="Faktuurdatum" />
                          </DefinedValue>
                          <DefinedValue>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[directpay]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_Faktuur]" Column="Totaal_Open" />
                          </DefinedValue>
                        </DefinedValues>
                        <Object Database="[directpay]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_Faktuur]" Index="[_dta_index_tbl_Faktuur_5_583009158__K13_K9_K19_K2_5]" />
                        <SeekPredicates>
                          <SeekPredicate>
                            <Prefix ScanType="EQ">
                              <RangeColumns>
                                <ColumnReference Database="[directpay]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_Faktuur]" Column="Afgehandeld_NeeJa" />
                              </RangeColumns>
                              <RangeExpressions>
                                <ScalarOperator ScalarString="(0)">
                                  <Const ConstValue="(0)" />
                                </ScalarOperator>
                              </RangeExpressions>
                            </Prefix>
                            <EndRange ScanType="LT">
                              <RangeColumns>
                                <ColumnReference Database="[directpay]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_Faktuur]" Column="Totaal_Open" />
                              </RangeColumns>
                              <RangeExpressions>
                                <ScalarOperator ScalarString="($0.0000)">
                                  <Const ConstValue="($0.0000)" />
                                </ScalarOperator>
                              </RangeExpressions>
                            </EndRange>
                          </SeekPredicate>
                          <SeekPredicate>
                            <Prefix ScanType="EQ">
                              <RangeColumns>
                                <ColumnReference Database="[directpay]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_Faktuur]" Column="Afgehandeld_NeeJa" />
                              </RangeColumns>
                              <RangeExpressions>
                                <ScalarOperator ScalarString="(0)">
                                  <Const ConstValue="(0)" />
                                </ScalarOperator>
                              </RangeExpressions>
                            </Prefix>
                            <StartRange ScanType="GT">
                              <RangeColumns>
                                <ColumnReference Database="[directpay]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[tbl_Faktuur]" Column="Totaal_Open" />
                              </RangeColumns>
                              <RangeExpressions>
                                <ScalarOperator ScalarString="($0.0000)">
                                  <Const ConstValue="($0.0000)" />
                                </ScalarOperator>
                              </RangeExpressions>
                            </StartRange>
                          </SeekPredicate>
                        </SeekPredicates>
                      </IndexScan>
                    </RelOp>
                  </Hash>
                </RelOp>
              </ComputeScalar>
            </RelOp>
          </QueryPlan>
        </StmtSimple>
      </Statements>
    </Batch>
  </BatchSequence>
</ShowPlanXML>
```

Comment: Different execution plans presumably. The `ISNULL()` makes the clause unsargable which means it can't use range seeks on any index on `money` and the number of rows estimated to result has probably changed. Please post the plans and also indicate estimated vs actual number of rows for both.

Comment: Yes the have different execution plans, what i don't understand is how the one is so much more efficient then the other. How do i get the estimated rows for a query?

Comment: Mouse over the arrows in the execution plans. Unsargable predicates are normally a bad thing but this time it may have just by luck either prevented the use of an unsuitable index or altered the estimated row count such that it happens to choose a better overall plan.

Comment: When i look at the plans i notice the Same index beeing used (both a seek) but different Predictates and the same thing applies for the Hash Match

Comment: Looks like the index is on `Afgehandeld_NeeJa, Totaal_Open` so it can still seek on the first part even when you make the `Totaal_Open` part unsargable. The only difference is the unsargable one needs to scan the whole of that section and evaluate the `Totaal_Open` part as a residual predicate. That should make it worse. Wondering if the slower one has a smaller memory grant and you are getting hash spills. You have only posted one actual execution plan (the other is an estimated plan) so I can't see the memory grants for both.

Comment: Now i'm sure smaller memory grant and hash spills tell you alot but how would i check something like this? Currently trying to change the Column to NOT NULL in a test environment just to see how that would affect the queries.

Comment: You can see the memory grant by looking at the XML for the plans. In your first one it is `MemoryGrant="1520"` but you haven't shown the actual plan for the second. You can use Profiler to trace hash spills. The estimated rows coming out of the hash aggregate is much less than the actual (9,019 vs 156,794) and in your other plan the estimated rows is even less (1322) so stands to reason it will get less memory. Presumably actual rows is still 156,794 so this is out by about a factor of 100.

Comment: The one without ISNULL seems to indeed have a smaller MemoryGrant="1024". What exactly would a Hash Spill mean and more importantly, is there anything i can do about them?

Comment: It seems to be estimating that there are many fewer distinct values of your `group by` column than actually materialise in reality so allocates a much too small amount of memory to build the hash table. This may mean it needs to spill to disc when the query runs out of memory. You could try updating statistics [other possible resolutions and more explanation here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlqueryprocessing/archive/2007/02/01/hash-warning-sql-profiler-event.aspx)

Comment: I do indeed get Hash Warning, on both queries actually, only three on the one without ISNULL and one on the one with ISNULL. I'll look into your resolutions/explanations when i get the chance. It's safe to say it's causing better results because this freak of nature event causes less Hash Spills then the "good" query and thus costing less time to execute? If so, please write that up and an answer and i'll mark it :)

Comment: Yes the estimated rows is much lower than actual on both. Are the [`EventSubClass`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190736(v=sql.105).aspx) values the same for both? Might be getting bailout on the slower one. Also the `integer data` column has some useful info [as described here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ialonso/archive/2012/09/05/what-s-the-maximum-level-of-recursion-for-the-hash-iterator-before-forcing-bail-out.aspx)

Comment: They both have 0 - Recursion as the EventSubClass and the IntegerData is 1,2,3 for the Without ISNULL and just 1 for the one with Is null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ISNULL()` version makes that part of the predicate [unsargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).

As well as meaning that it can't use your index as effectively (it can still seek into the leading column from the other predicate in the query) this also makes the construct more opaque to the optimiser when it comes to estimating the number of rows that will match.

Both plans have an estimated 27,420 rows going into the hash match operator but they differ in how many estimated rows come out. The faster plan estimates 9,019 and the slower one 1,322.

Both of these estimates are in fact very wrong as in reality there are 156,794 distinct values of your group by column. As a result of the bad estimates neither query is allocated enough memory to build the hash table and both need to spill to disc. The slower one is particularly memory starved and so this happens multiple times.

You could try updating your existing statistics or looking at creating some multi column statistics in order to try and get a more accurate estimate of the number of distinct group by items that will be returned and thus either a different plan or more memory allocated.

Comment: Ye, looking into the statistics update now, i'm using IndexOptimize from http://ola.hallengren.com/ (although i should most likely get the latest version since it's been a while). Wondering if something is going wrong there, i'll look into it atleast. Thanks alot for your help, advice and guidance :)

Comment: The statistics on the index are up to date but the wrong estimates remain. I'll just write this one down to beeing caused by horrible database design.

Comment: @F.B.tenKate - You could maybe try creating some [multi column statistics](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ianjo/archive/2005/11/10/491548.aspx) on `Afgehandeld_NeeJa, Totaal_Open, debiteur_id`

Comment: I tried that already, no dice! It's just horrible at estimating... I wouldn't be suprised SQL Server refuses to even try and make sense of it all just out of principal (yes, the meta data is _that_ bad)

Answer (score 0):

Adding two filtered, covering indices might help (the question why is ISNULL helping the speed is already answered):

```
USE Directpay

/*
    SELECT    debiteur_id, MIN(Faktuurdatum) AS OldestOpenInvoiceDate, ISNULL(SUM(Totaal_Open),0) AS TotalOpenAmount
    FROM    dbo.tbl_Faktuur 
    WHERE   (Afgehandeld_NeeJa = 0 OR Afgehandeld_NeeJa IS NULL)
    AND        (ISNULL(Totaal_Open,0) <> 0) 
    --AND        (Totaal_Open <> 0) 
    GROUP BY debiteur_id
*/

-- Prepare two filtered indices to split the OR condition
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_tbl_faktuur_debiteur_id_faktuurdatum_flt_1 ON tbl_Faktuur (debiteur_id, faktuurdatum) 
INCLUDE (Totaal_Open)
WHERE   (Afgehandeld_NeeJa = 0);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_tbl_faktuur_debiteur_id_faktuurdatum_flt_2 ON tbl_Faktuur (debiteur_id, faktuurdatum) 
INCLUDE (Totaal_Open)
WHERE   (Afgehandeld_NeeJa IS NULL);


-- Rewrite the query
SELECT     debiteur_id
         , min(OldestOpenInvoiceDate)     AS OldestOpenInvoiceDate
         , isnull(sum(TotalOpenAmount),0) AS TotalOpenAmount
FROM
(
    SELECT debiteur_id
         , min(Faktuurdatum)           AS OldestOpenInvoiceDate
         , sum(Totaal_Open)            AS TotalOpenAmount
    FROM     dbo.tbl_Faktuur
    WHERE    Afgehandeld_NeeJa = 0
    GROUP BY debiteur_id

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT debiteur_id
         , min(Faktuurdatum)           AS OldestOpenInvoiceDate
         , sum(Totaal_Open)            AS TotalOpenAmount
    FROM     dbo.tbl_Faktuur
    WHERE    Afgehandeld_NeeJa IS NULL
    GROUP BY debiteur_id
) Unhandled
GROUP BY debiteur_id
```

Comment: We're running SQL Server 2005 though, so although a valid suggestion if running 2008 or higher this will not be possible for us.

Comment: In that case, try to create the index where the colum from the filter is moved to the first position in the index - it might still be a better option than the one suggested by the DTA, specifically if the number of unhandled records is much smaller than the number of handled ones. Also, I've slightly modified your query and removed the ISNULL check from the where clause.